# Para que serve string.maketrans?

Tags: python

Eu estava dando uma olhada em uns desafios de Python e encontrei um que envolvia rotacionar os caracteres de uma string. Do tipo 'a' vira 'c', 'b' vira 'd', e no final 'y' vira 'a' e 'z' vira 'b'.

Enquanto resolvia o problema, vi uma indicação de que o melhor a se fazer era usar `string.maketrans`, mas não faço ideia do que a função faz, ou como usá-la.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `maketrans` serve para mapear os caracteres de forma que eles sejam correspondentes. Primeiro você passa uma string com os caracteres que serão "traduzidos", depois o mapeamento dele, onde a posição um do mapa, corresponde a tradução do primeiro elemento da string repassada.
Isso pode ser visto no exemplo a seguir:

```
from string import maketrans

char_a_ser_convertida = 'abcdef'
mapa_de_traducao = 'ABCDEF'
traducao = maketrans(char_a_ser_convertida, mapa_de_traducao)
str = 'abcg'
print str.translate(traducao)
```

O output desse `print` será:

```
ABCg
```

Veja que ele converteu apenas os caracteres mapeados para os seus caracteres correspondentes no mapa. Basicamente o que ele faz é traduzir um caracter para um elemento corresponde na string de mapeamento.

Comment: Faz sentido então. Se eu criar um mapa com todo o alfabeto, dá pra resolver o problema de um jeito bem simples... Valeu!